# MySQL foreign key restrictions are not being saved

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.25 and trying to create a foreign key from `id_parent` to `id` on the same table.

```
CREATE TABLE `acl_roles` (
`id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 `id_parent` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 KEY `FK_acl_roles` (`id_parent`),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 CONSTRAINT `FK_acl_roles` FOREIGN KEY (`id_parent`) REFERENCES `acl_roles` (`id`)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When I do

```
ALTER TABLE `acl_roles` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_acl_roles` FOREIGN KEY (`id_parent`) REFERENCES `acl_roles` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;
```

For some reason the latter executes without error yet when I execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE acl_roles` I get the exact same schema and the restrictions are not applied no matter how many times I run the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT` is the default behavior for FK constraints, that is why you see no difference when viewing the schema. It is implied.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to make this explicit. Thanks!